# Why does my importrange query fail when I "wrap" with arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following formula which is currently returning the expected results -

```
=join(",",query(importrange(vlookup(mid(G4,1,find(",",G4)-1),xref,2,false),vlookup(mid(G4,1,find(",",G4)-1),xref,3,false)),"Select Col3,Col6,Col9 where Col1 = '"&mid(G4,find(",",G4)+1,20)&"' "))
```

However, I naturally want to make this as dynamic and flexible as possible so I would like to "wrap" it in an arrayformula which ends up like this -

```
=arrayformula(join(",",query(importrange(vlookup(mid(G4:G,1,find(",",G4:G)-1),xref,2,false),vlookup(mid(G4:G,1,find(",",G4:G)-1),xref,3,false)),"Select Col3,Col6,Col9 where Col1 = '"&mid(G4:G,find(",",G4:G)+1,20)&"' ")))
```

This formula gives me "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMNCol3" error.

I tried to include an iferror to try to trap some error but this made no difference.

I tried various angles to debug and basically focussed on the importrange not providing the data to the query once it was wrapped by the arrayformula. I tried to explicitly reference the external sheet key and range in the importange function, instead of using the lookups, and this did give me a result - but only in the first cell. There should also have been a result returned about 4 rows down.

If I copy the formula down the column, I do get the expected result 4 rows down, but this obviously defeats the purpose of the arrayformula.

In my research in the Google forums there were some suggestions that arrayformula and importrange may not play well together, but no hard and fast facts.

I noticed in this forum that the combination of the two functions has been mentioned but no indication that they did not work together, so I am wondering if there is just some little thing I am missing in my syntax that is causing my ideal scenario not to work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this will work for a couple of reasons.

Firstly, not all the functions in Google Sheets can be automated using an arrayformula, and QUERY is one of them.  As far as I know this is because the output of QUERY can be an array itself, so it is not possible to iterate an array output across another array (i.e. your results range).

Secondly, JOIN works across a either a single row or column, whereas your query outputs 3 columns.  The arrayformula result would therefore consist of an array with multiple rows and columns, which JOIN cannot use.

I think the best solution is to use the IFERROR as you've described, and copy the single-row formula down the entire column - that way the blank records will not show as errors, but you will be able to add new values to column G and they will be picked up automatically.

Comment: Thanks Chris. As the intent of the formula was only ever to return a single result (the lookup should be a 1:1 rather than 1 to many), I did not consider the implications of multiple results. Thanks for your insights.